# Why are the two divs in my grid on different layers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a problem that has been stuck me for a while and I want to ask for help.

This component uses React and Tailwind.

Because I want to use the drop and drag of frame motion to exchange the image in the two divs, but I found that when I was exchanging images, the left image would  under the right div, and I didn’t set any z-index in the two divs, I searched for a long time, but I don’t know why the two divs are not on the same layer, so I ask for help, thank you guys!

This is my code and layer image

```
 return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2  ">
      <div className="border border-white w-full rounded-l-3xl bg-self grid  ">
        {oneLeftImg && oneLeftImg.url !== defaultImage && (
          <img
            src={oneLeftImg.url}
            alt={oneLeftImg.name}
            className="justify-self-center self-center absolute max-h-[90%] "
          />
        )}
        <button
          className="text-gray-400 text-2xl h-6 justify-self-end mr-2 mt-2"
          onClick={() => handleRemoveClick("oneLeft")}
        >
          <BsFillDashCircleFill />
        </button>
        <label htmlFor="uploadoneLeft" className="justify-self-center">
          <BsUpload className="text-4xl  text-gray-400 justify-self-center" />
          <input
            type="file"
            id="uploadoneLeft"
            onChange={(e) => handleImageUpload(e, "oneLeft")}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="border border-white w-full rounded-r-3xl bg-self  grid   ">
        {oneRightImg && oneRightImg.url !== defaultImage && (
          <img
            src={oneRightImg.url}
            alt={oneRightImg.name}
            className="justify-self-center self-center absolute max-h-[90%] "
          />
        )}
        <button
          className="text-gray-400  text-2xl h-6 justify-self-end mr-2 mt-2"
          onClick={() => handleRemoveClick("oneRight")}
        >
          <BsFillDashCircleFill />
        </button>
        <label htmlFor="uploadoneRight" className="justify-self-center ">
          <BsUpload className="text-4xl text-gray-400" />
          <input
            type="file"
            id="uploadoneRight"
            onChange={(e) => handleImageUpload(e, "oneRight")}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

[image]

I hope this problem can be solved and know where the problem is,Thx!

Comment: [MDN: Stacking without z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

Comment: Thank you, but I also tried to remove the absolute in the image but it is still not on the same layer.

Comment: All elements are on a different layer in [the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). They follow the rules mentioned in the first link.